# Center box grid horizontally and vertically with stamp in the middle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The website I am building requires to have grid of images where one image is in the middle no matter how many images there are in the grid. This is in fluid layout and images are supposed to be editable by website admin and only height is fixed.

Image explanation:
[image: images fill full viewable area of the div they are in]

I was thinking to use something as [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) or [Packery](http://packery.metafizzy.co/) but those don't provide any centred layout options. What approach would you take to sort this out?

Comment: Not sure why the down/close votes. This seems like a logical, thought-out question.

Comment: @FreeAsInBeer I din't, but might be it's off topic as to find tools and utilities or it's an opinion based question... and for me it's even unclear what the OP's question is...

Comment: Well, the question is how to make this layout work, haha. I am not sure how to put it better. I'd be able to make it horizontally and vertically centred but the problem is the stamp which has to be in the middle every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To approach this problem, I would have each row of images be inside of a container. Then you could absolutely position the container based upon calculations to center the "stamp."

Comment: Yes, that would solve it I believe.. Simple, my brain is not working I assume. Thanks